# Condition based Foreign Key in Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core-2.2

I have to create a condition based one to many relationship between classes. I have the following classes.

```
public enum Type
{
    Type1,
    Type2
}
public Class Base1
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Prop {get; set;}
    public List<NProp> NProps {get; set;}
}
public Class Base2
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Prop {get; set;}
    public List<NProp> NProps {get; set;}
}
public class NProp
{
    public Type Type {get; set;}
    public int BaseId {get; set;} //Foreign Key
    public string NProp {get; set;}
}
```

Now, in class NProp, there is one foreign key `baseId` which should be a foreign key of `Base1` if the `Type` is `Type1` and to that of `Base2` if the `Type` is `Type2`.
First of all, is this possible? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. You should use two FKs. One for each Base.